# The right tense in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, past-perfect

Consider:

> I left the taxi and stood beside the freeway under the rain (without any umbrella and hat), to catch  another taxi, but after (passing?) 10 mintues, (still?) no taxi stopped/had stopped? for? me in that rainy weather.

What is the proper tense for "stop" in the sentence above? Are the words in parentheses make it more fluent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, it isn't "standed" but "stood". Furthermore, it would be better to replace "beside" with "alongside", but this isn't necessary, and "under the rain" needs to be "in the rain".

Back to your question. The correct tense would be "had stopped", since you are talking about an action (not) happening during another action in the past.

About the words in brackets: "without any umbrella and hat" might make it seem like *they* need to catch a taxi, so you might not want to include it. Furthermore, it would be correct to say "after 10 minutes had passed". "Still" isn't necessary either, but it can be included.